# Teradata SQL Query to filter only those rows who has entry for all period ids

Tags: sql, date, count, teradata, window-functions

I have a dataset with 3 columns (ID, YYYYMM, sales). I wanted to have only those IDs who record is present for every YYYYMM (201909 to 202003).

I want to have the date at ID and YYYYMM level itself. I dont want to use group by and have the dataset reduced to one ID row.

Comment: What is the data type of YYYYMM?

Answer (score 0):

You could use window functions and a `qualify` clause:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
qualify count(*) over(partition by id) 
    = 1 + max(floor(yyyymm / 100) * 12 + (yyymmm mod 100)) over() 
        - min(floor(yyyymm / 100) * 12 + (yyymmm mod 100)) over()
```

The `qualify` clause counts how many records exist for the current `id`, and compares it to the overal count of `yyyymmdd`s, which can be computed by substracting its max and min values (this assumes that this is a numeric value, as it looks).

Comment: As there's no month 13-99 & 0 your max-min calculation results in 94 :-)

Comment: @dnoeth: ah yes, of course... Thanks for pointing this out! OK I did (attempt to) fix the arithmetics.

Comment: Can you not do `count(distinct yyyymm) over()` to get the total number of months?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . I think this does what you want:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where yyyymm >= 201909 and
      yyyymm <= 202003
qualify count(*) over (partition by id) = 6;
```